# How do I stringify a nested object to make graphql/GET request using queryParams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I need to make a request from my node server, to a graphQL API. The graphQL API I am using takes the `query` as the URL's query params, not in the body of the request. It also does not accept POST requests.  I am having an issue stringifying something like

```
const query = {
    student(id: studentId) {
      personal {
        address
        grade
        etc {morestuff}
      }
    }
  }
```

how do I stringify this to send it as queryParams? I have tried the `querystring` module `querystring(query)` but it returns something like `student=` and that's it. I have tried JSON.stringify and was also unsuccessful. I need the above, to look like:

```
query=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20student(id%3A%20studentId)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20personal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20grade%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20etc%20%7Bmorestuff%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D
```

(I used an online encoder/decoder for that!)

I know that there are GraphQL client libs out there but I am unsure if they are to be used server-to-server, I see them used from browser/clients. If I should be using a client lib, can you recommend one (a lightweight preferably) that supports GET requests (the last one I tried did not - it was called Prisma)

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

this works for me, creating a function:

```
function encode(query) {
  return encodeURIComponent(query).replace(/'/g, "%27").replace(/"/g, "%22");
}
```

and passing:

```
const query = {
    student(id: studentId) {
      personal {
        address
        grade
        etc {morestuff}
      }
    }
  }
```

returns desired results. Hope this helps someone.